# Escape NSDateFormatter String

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to escape characters from `NSDateFormatter` format?

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy \\a\\t HH:mm"];
NSString *dateFormated = [dateFormater stringFromDate:currentDate];

NSLog(@"%@", dateFormated);
```

Comment: Bookmark the [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) page in the docs as well as the [IEEE Date Format Specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Anyone working with `NSDateFormatter` should read these pages.

Comment: @rmaddy that is true, and I do. but the bit on escaping is pretty easy to miss

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can escape text by enclosing it in single quotes:

```
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm"];
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];   
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];   
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];   
NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString); 
// For US English, the output may be: 
// formattedDateString: 2001-01-02 at 13:00
```

Comment: If you want to escape a single quote, put a single quote twice in escaped text (`' it''s '`)