# Localize NSDateFormatter which has a custom string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsdateformatter

I want to localize NSDateFomatter, which has 'at' word in between date and time. Any idea how to do it?

```
//Create date formatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d 'at' h:mm a"];
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
```

Comment: Check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16570725/3378413

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape NSDateFormatter String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570659/escape-nsdateformatter-string)

Comment: What do you mean by localize?  Are you referring to the date and time formatting, or just the word 'at'?

Comment: Actually both together, date and time formatting will be localized by the system. But, I want to localize whole string to be localized (eg: Nov 27 at 5:30) something like this...

Comment: Add localized formats to your `Localizable.strings` file and load it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this harder than it needs to be.

If you use `NSDateFormatterLongStyle` for both the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`, then `NSDateFormatter` will give you something like "November 30, 2015 at 3:35:32 PM MST". You can adjust that by using different built-in styles. For example if you set the `timeStyle` to `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` but keep `dateStyle` as `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`, the result is something like "November 30, 2015 at 3:36 PM". **Don't use `dateFormat`, let `NSDateFormatter` figure out the localization for you**.

This gives you the "at" when in the USA (for example), but `NSDateFormatter` will convert this into a format appropriate for the current locale. As a result you'll get something appropriate for however the locale normally represents time and date, but you don't need to tell it to use the word "at" or try to figure out how to translate it.